# set_select() helper function is not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, select

I have used some codes as below,

```
<select class="form-control selection" name="currency">
                        <option value="">select currency</option>
                            <option value="AED"<?php echo set_select('currency', 'AED'); ?> >AED</option>
                            <option value="SAR"<?php echo set_select('currency', 'SAR'); ?> >SAR</option>
                            <option value="MAD"<?php echo set_select('currency', 'MAD'); ?> >MAD</option>
                            <option value="TRY"<?php echo set_select('currency', 'TRY'); ?> >TRY</option>
                        </select>
```

But unfortunately it is not showing selected value after failed form validation. Why this basic set_select() method is not working? I have used this in some other fields and all that working fine

Comment: Are you passing the currency to form validation? can you show your form validation rule?

Comment: @kumar_v : Thanks buddy :) I did not give that currency for validation. Now added. And it is working too :)

Comment: Let me post as answer. So it will be helpful for others too:-)

Comment: please give 1 up for my question too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before using `set_value()`, `set_select()`,`set_checkbox()`, `set_radio()`, you have to pass those fields to validation even if not required / validated.

Comment: `you have to pass those fields to validation` Not necessarily. While this would resolve this specific problem, It's not a general rule.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

There are **only two cases** when you use CodeIgnIter `set_*` form helper functions:

1. The `Form_validation` library is not loaded.
2. Validation object is instantiated (you are using `Form_validation` library).

In order to use `set_*` helper functions, you **don't have to** use Form validation library necessarily, **But** if you're using the validation library, You **MUST** set at least a validation rule for that *field*.

## Long Answer  (set_* Anatomy)

The following is true for all of the `set_*` form helper functions. But I'll try to describe how [`set_select()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L707) works:

**Syntax:** `set_select($field = '', $value = '', $default = FALSE)`

### 1. Without using Form validation

When you use `set_select()` function, CodeIgniter uses the [`_get_validation_object()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L1031-L1049) function to [look for the validation object](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L1045-L1048).

The `_get_validation_object()` returns either the `object` or `FALSE` (if the validation is not loaded yet).

When it returns `FALSE`, The `set_select()` function search through `$_POST` variable to find the specified `field` name in the array, and in the following [by checking function argouments](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L715-L739) such as `$value` and `$default`, it determines whether to return the `selected="selected"` attribute/value or an empty string `''`.

So, it works without using the Form validation library.

### 2. While using Form validation

But if the validation library is loaded before, the `set_select()` function [will pass the arguments](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L742) to the [`Form_validation::set_select()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L759) method, and returns the result.

In the `Form_validation` class, there is a private property called `_field_data` which is an array containing all the **field** names/values (**those you've set validation rules for them**).

`Form_validation::set_select()` method checks the existence of the `field` in `_field_data` array, and returns an **empty** string on failure.

The `_field_data` array [is populated by](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L138-L147) validation [`set_rules()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L74) method.

**Hence, if you're using the validation library, you have to set at least a validation rule for your `field` to get `set_select()` form helper function to work.**

That's why you couldn't get it to work.

I hope this answer helps get a good understanding of `set_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Modify the `set_select` function in the form helper from:

```
if (count($_POST) === 0)
{
    return ' selected="selected"';
}
```

to

```
if (count($_POST) === 0)
{
    if ($default)
    {
        return ' selected="selected"';
    }
    else
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: @joelcj. Do not change the core code. It is not right answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

As they said, codeigniter set select works only if you are validating those fields. If that fields are not required then no need repopulation right